# Using a generic type as a return type of an async method

Tags: c#, .net, generics, async-await

A previous question made me wonder why the following method would raise a compile time error:

> The return type of an async method must be void, Task or Task

```
public async T MyMethodAsync<T>() where T : Task
{
     // Irrelevant code here which returns a Task
}
```

Since we know at compile time that T is always a `Task` or a derived type, why won't this work?

**Edit**

The reason I'm asking is that a method may return a `Task` or a `Task<T>`. Let's say the method can return either and I don't want to duplicate code.

Of course this is all theoretical and isn't ment for production purposes.

**Edit 2**

Found a great article by Lucian Wischik:
[*Why must async return Task*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2012/11/22/why-must-async-methods-return-task.aspx)

Comment: Did you mean to make that a generic method?

Comment: Did you miss the generic definition for the function? It should be `MyMethodAsync<T>()`. Also are you returning a `T` or a `Task`? If you return the later you can just make the return type `Task`.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a reason for the compiler to refuse this, but stepping back I have to wonder why a generic with `where T : AnySpecificType` needs to be generic in the first place.

Comment: The return type might be a `Task<T>` for example

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: Please try to write a method body which would be valid for `T=Task` and also for `T=Task<string>`.

Comment: Async methods lift a regular type into a task type, and the return type of the method is `Task` or `Task<T>` depending on whether a value is returned. The compiler doesn't have some general way of creating values some arbitrary derived type `T`.

Comment: You cannot do both `Task` and `Task<T>` in one method, you will need to write two methods, although there are several ways to interop between the two (the most common being a `Task<object>` that returns `null`)

Comment: Shot in the dark, did you already use the name Task in one of your own classes? You can always specify the name in a using directive if that is the case. `using AsyncTask = System.Threading.Tasks.Task;`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Three problems:

- Just because `T` is "`Task` or a derived type" doesn't mean that it's `Task` or `Task<T>`. What would you expect if I called `MyMethodAsync<MyCustomTask>` where `MyCustomTask` derives from `Task`?
- The compiler needs to know whether it's building a state machine returning `Task` or `Task<T>` when it compiles the method - it uses different helper classes in the different cases
- If an async method has a return type of `Task`, any `return` statements can't specify a value; if it has a return type of `Task<T>` any `return` statements must specify a value which is implicitly convertible to `T`. How can that work within `MyMethodAsync`? It's a bit like saying "my method is either `void` or returns a `T` - you can decide when you call it".

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve here, but basically this isn't going to work.

Comment: I see. So basically this has to do with the compiler needing to know if there isn't a return value (if its a `Task`) or if there is (`Task<T>`). As for `MyCustomTask`, is a derived type of `Task` applicable as a return type of an `async` method?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: No, it's not - but it *would* meet your generic type parameter constraint.

Comment: May I ask why? Or would that be a different question?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: Why what? Why it's not a valid return type? How would you expect the compiler to know how to construct one? Bear in mind that the compiler turns the async method into a state machine, and works out how to return a `Task` or `Task<T>` if necessary. It does that via helper classes that are specific to `Task` or `Task<T>`.

Comment: Right, now I get it. I wasn't aware of the problem of inferring an unknown derived task type. I should explore those helper classes to understand exactly what happeneds.

Comment: The biggest problem is the fact that the compiler introduces code that creates an instance of the return type, not the user. For `Task` and `Task<T>`, it knows how to do that. If the return type of the method were `MyCustomTask`, then even if `MyCustomTask` was derived from `Task` the compiler would not know the correct way to create an instance of that type to return.

Comment: Found a great article about that. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2012/11/22/why-must-async-methods-return-task.aspx

Answer (score -1):

I cannot think of a valid definition of `MyMethodAsync` that would allow it to return a generic `T` derived from `Task` without knowing at compile time what that type is or taking a parameter of some kind.

If you are really returning a `Task` or `Task<T>` then you can update your signature to reflect that fact and avoid the problem.

If you honestly need some type derived from `Task` then you will need to rewrite your logic to instead return `Task` or `Task<T>` and wrap around that other type. Assuming that is unacceptable you will need to drop the `async` and handle the state machine yourself.