# How to make async method generic over Task type

Tags: c#, generics, asynchronous

My question is on the surface very similar to [Using a generic type as a return type of an async method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23939396/268898).  However, he did not have a real world usage scenario and so all that could be stated is that you can't do that.  I understand from [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23939495/268898) to that question and from the blog post [Why must async methods return Task?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2012/11/22/why-must-async-methods-return-task.aspx) why it is not supported.  The post discusses workarounds, but none of them apply to my use case.

*My question is, what is the best way to work around the language limitation given what I am trying to do?*

In production code, we had a retry method that takes a `Func<Task>` and returns `Task`.  We then needed to be able to retry `TaskT>` functions as well.  So we changed the retry method to (slightly simplified):

```
public static async T Retry<T>(Func<T> action) where T : Task
{
    for (var i = 0; ; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            return await action();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            if (i >= 3)
                throw;
        }       
    }
}
```

The compiler of course reports the error "The return type of an async method must be void, Task or Task".  Can I make `Retry` work with both `Task` and `Task<T>` without writing two copies of the method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, async just doesn't support that. The simplest option to fake it would be:

```
public static async Task<T> Retry<T>(Func<Task<T>> action)
{
    for (var i = 0; ; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            return await action();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            if (i >= 3)
                throw;
        }       
    }
}

public static async Task Retry(Func<Task> action)
{
    Func<Task<int>> d = async () => { await action(); return 0; };
    await Retry(d);
}
```

That doesn't involve code duplication, but you do end up with an awful lot of layers of tasks on top of each other when you call the non-generic version. You could change the latter to:

```
public static Task Retry(Func<Task> action)
{
    Func<Task<int>> d = async () => { await action(); return 0; };
    return Retry(d);
}
```

Then it will *actually* return a `Task<int>`, but assuming your callers don't care, it does save one bit of redirection.