# Polly Retry policy with Function is not waiting for result

Tags: c#, policy, polly, retry-logic

I am trying to convert my existing function to Polly Retry policy

```
public static T Execute<T>(Func<T> getTask) where T : Task
{
    var retryCount = 3;
    while (retryCount-- > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            getTask().Wait();
            return getTask();
        } catch(Exception ex){
            // handle retry
        }
    }
}
```

Converted to this

```
public static T Execute<T>(Func<T> func) where T : Task
{
    var task = func();
    Policy.Handle<HttpRequestException>()
        .Or<TimeoutException>()
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(
            3,
            retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(5, retryAttempt)),
            (exception, timeSpan, retryCount, context) =>
            {
                //do some logging
            })
        .ExecuteAsync(func).Wait();
    return task;
}
```

and test code is

```
var retryCount = 0;
var res = HttpRetryWrapper.Execute(() => Task.Factory.StartNew<string>(function: () =>
{
    if (++retryCount == 3)
    {
        return "fake";
    }
    throw new TimeoutException();
}));
```

when I assert the `res` value, I am not getting the right result. Debugging traces me into point where the `Execution` is not waiting for results properly.

The number of calls to `test function` is correct. However the logging is messed up and the final result is not having result `fake`

Comment: Pretty much never use `Wait`. Try making the function async and awaiting inside

Comment: You also just return the `task` local var, which is not used by your policy. Polly is calling func on its own.

Comment: @JamesFaix  this is the one contract which I can't break `public static T Execute<T>(Func<T> func) where T : Task`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a helper method for async executions through a hard-coded Polly policy, where the executions asynchronously return a type `TResult`, via a `Task<TResult>`, you could adopt:

```
public static Task<TResult> ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> func) 
{
    return Policy.Handle<HttpRequestException>()
        .Or<TimeoutException>()
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(
            3,
            retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(5, retryAttempt)),
            (exception, timeSpan, retryCount, context) =>
            {
                //do some logging
            })
        .ExecuteAsync<TResult>(func); // This is an async-await-eliding contraction of: .ExecuteAsync<TResult>(async () => await func());
    }
```

(Given the policy used is the same every time, you could consider also storing the policy in a static field and creating it only once.)

*Note:* This (intentionally) doesn't conform to the contract stated in your comment to your original question, as being unbreakable:

```
public static T Execute<T>(Func<T> func) where T : Task
```

The clause `where T : Task` initially looks appealing for an or async async-*like* method designed to work with either `Task` or `Task<T>`.  Jon Skeet explains [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23939495/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34028208/) why it doesn't work with async.  Your proposed helper method signature is not in-itself async:

```
public static T Execute<T>(Func<T> func) where T : Task
```

However, introducing `.ExecuteAsync(async () => await func());` in your example code forces a similar issue.  The Polly `.ExecuteAsync(...)` overload, precisely in order to play nicely with `async`/`await`, exists in two main forms:

(1) `Task ExecuteAsync(Func<Task> func)`

(2) `Task<TResult> ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> func)`

The compiler has to *select one or the other at compile time*: it can't (in your example code) compile it to be *either* (1) or (2) *at runtime*.  Since it only knows `T : Task` it selects (1), which returns `Task`.  Hence the error you see in your comment to @JamesFaix's answer: `Cannot implicitly convert type Task to T`.

If you want helper patterns of this form, which callers can use for either `Task` or `Task<TResult>` -returning calls, you would have to declare both:

```
class HttpRetryWrapper
{
    private static policy = Policy.Handle<HttpRequestException>()
        .Or<TimeoutException>()
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(
            3,
            retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(5, retryAttempt)),
            (exception, timeSpan, retryCount, context) =>
            {
                //do some logging
            });

    public static Task ExecuteAsync(Func<Task> func) 
    {
        return policy.ExecuteAsync(func);
    }

    public static Task<TResult> ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> func) 
    {
        return policy.ExecuteAsync<TResult>(func);
    }
}
```

---

Finally, if this is for wrapping calls placed through `HttpClient`, the recommended pattern is to place the Polly policies in a `DelegatingHandler` as described in @MuhammedRehanSaeed's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35183487/).  ASP.NET Core 2.1 supports concise declaration for creating such `DelegatingHandler`s [using IHttpClientFactory](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is

```
public static T Execute<T>(Func<T> func) where T : Task
{
    return Policy.Handle<HttpRequestException>()
        .Or<TimeoutException>()
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(
            3,
            retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(5, retryAttempt)),
            (exception, timeSpan, retryCount, context) =>
            {
                //do some logging
            })
        .ExecuteAsync(func).Wait();
}
```

In your code example, you were invoking `func` once and returning that, and then in between defining and invoking a policy, but not returning the result of invoking that policy.

If you want to avoid `Wait` I think you could also do

```
public static T Execute<T>(Func<T> func) where T : Task
{
    return Policy.Handle<HttpRequestException>()
        .Or<TimeoutException>()
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(
            3,
            retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(5, retryAttempt)),
            (exception, timeSpan, retryCount, context) =>
            {
                //do some logging
            })
        .ExecuteAsync(async () => await func());
}
```

Comment: I started with that. ran into issue
`Cannot implicitly convert type Task to T`. When I explicit cast, running into run time exceptions

Comment: Maybe you just want `Execute` and not `ExecuteAsync`.